# In EF Core, connection string to one of several local databases on SQL server developer edition?

Tags: entity-framework-core, database-connection

I am new to EF Core and following guide in the introduction: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/

I have a VS 22 console app with the EF Core nuget package installed, and several Microsoft SQL Server Developer edition databases (Not SQL Server Express).

I am having trouble connecting to my databasea and would like to ask your help to get the connection string right.

If I use the generic `Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb`, then calling add-migration and update-database does not generate an error, but the added table does not show up in any of my local databases.

In SSMS, the desired SQL database is called PC-NAME\MSSQLSERVER. What would I need to write in the connection string `Server=...` in order to connect to this particular database?

```
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(
                @"Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=Blogging;Trusted_Connection=True");
        }
```

Thanks in advance,
Mike

Comment: Read this cheat sheet: [SQL Server connection strings](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/)